# Video indexing issues on pages without videos

Tags: google-search-console

We received an e-mail from Google regarding video indexing issues: "Video indexing issues found on your sites". Google gives us a list of pages where the video is not processed, thus returning those videos as not indexed.

The problem with this is that those pages do not have a video on them, so I don't really get why Google shows us those issues.

Does it have something to do with the HTML of the webpage or is Google not indexing videos  the right way? Did someone have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue, videos are not there on the page and the Google reporting errors, e.g. https://summitmtnlodge.com/policies-and-disclaimers/

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to zero in on the exact cause of the issue without looking at a few example URLs. My best guess at this point is that your page HTML does have at least one video tag somewhere, even if the video is not rendered on the page.

For example, the page that @Wasim Sayyed has linked to is an innocent-looking "Policies and Disclaimers" page, but does have at least one video tag buried within a "lightbox" waiting for some kind of user event trigger to enable it.

[image]

Your best bet in such cases is to talk to your website's dev team and see how best to optimize the HTML. The solution may vary vastly depending on your website's particular tech stack.